# Can I use the Power Grid Expansion "Northern Europe / United Kingdom & Ireland"?

Tags: power-grid

[image]

I just bought the Power Grid expansion pack *Northern Europe / United Kingdom & Ireland*.
If you look at the photo, you will see the label **Recharged Version** and, at the bottom, you will see the following warning:

> The maps and power plant cards of Northern Europe/United Kingdom &
>   Ireland in this expansion can only be played with a copy of Power
>   Grid.

I have *Power Grid 2004* from Rio Grande Games. Will I be able to use the extension with my copy of Power Grid , or will I have to buy *Power Grid Recharged*. It's still shrink-wrapped, so I could return it if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use the expansion with your existing copy of Power Grid,
with one caveat: the backs of the power plant cards have changed, which means you need to shuffle the deck while both the fronts, *and* backs are hidden when using the **Northern Europe** part of the expansion.

If you chose to use only the **United Kingdom & Ireland** part of the expansion no adjustments are needed.

Comment: Great news. I followed your advice and removed the shrink wrap. At the very start of the rules, it's written: 
«The maps and cards of Northern Europe/United Kingdom and Ireland in this expansion can only be played with a copy of Power Grid (Recharged Version) or Power Grid.»